# Eager Loading Laravel 5 many-to-many relationship with two foreign keys

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading

In my application, I have two tables, a **Users** table and a **Forms** table.  The **Users** table is your typical user info with id, and the **Forms** table has a list of fields a user would need to complete.  The many-many relationship is being tracked in my **UserForms** pivot table like so:

- id
- form_id (fk -> forms)
- sender_id (fk -> users)
- receiver_id (fk -> users)
- completed

A user may send another user a form to that he/she needs to complete, and a user can both send and receive many forms. A form may therefore have many users associated with it.  The problem is when I bring up a form and try to eager load the relationship containing the User info for both the sender *and* receiver (since there are two foreign keys). It seems like I can only do one or the other.  My form model looks like so:

**Form.php**

```
class Form extends Model
{
    public function senders() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_forms', 'form_id', 'sender_id')->withPivot('receiver_id', 'completed');
    }

    public function receivers() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_forms', 'form_id', 'receiver_id')->withPivot('sender_id', 'completed');
    }
}
```

**FormController**:

```
public function show( $id )
{
    $form = Form::with('receivers')->findOrFail($id);  
    return view('form.show', ['form' => $form]);
}
```

**view.blade.php**

```
@foreach( $form->receivers as $receiver )
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $receiver->full_name }} </td>
        <td>{{ $receiver->pivot->sender_id }} </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

How can I get it to load the **User** attributed to *sender_id*, so I could do something like this in my view:

```
{{ $receiver->pivot->sender->full_name }}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use relationships with implicit pivot tables.

You could however create a FormUser model, setup the according hasMany and belongs to relations and then access the relations from there.

Maybe I should explain that a bit more.
Your FormUser would have two belongsTo relations (both pointing to the users table) and your view code would look like this:

```
@foreach( $form->formusers as $relation )
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $relation->receiver->full_name }} </td>
        <td>{{ $relation->sender->full_name }} </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```